How to make items with fixed width occupy the full width of the parent element?
I want grid items with a fixed width to span the full width of their parent container, leaving equal spacing between them. How can I achieve a similar layout using CSS Grid or Flexbox?
Here’s the example code I’m working with:


.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 25px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: span 4;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(5) {
   grid-column: 3 / span 4;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>



This is how it should look (with the first item aligned to the left and the fourth item aligned to the right edges of the parent view):


So, why not use flex? What result are you hoping to achieve exactly, can you share a picture of the desired outcome? What's the problem with what you have?

@DavidThomas I added the screenshot of how it should look (with the first item aligned to the left and the fourth item aligned to the right edges of the parent view).
If you can make the exact result by using flexbox, please share your solution.

grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
add this in your .grid class
where

auto-fit ::will automatically fill as many as grid items within the available space
minmax   :: each item will have min width of 50px and grow equally up to 1fr


I think (but am not completely sure!) OP wants the items to remain a fixed width (which is set at 50px in the question's code) and the gaps to increase, as they would if using flex justify-content: space-between.

@AHaworth you're right. The width is one of the problems here. Another issue is centering the second row while ensuring the first row uses justify-content: space-between.
Let me know if you'd like further refinements!
